# ScreenManager root is working perfectly excepting one code line

Tags: python, kivy

I try to learn python and kivy by doing a quiz app. Everything worked fine for me until now. After I log in the app , and i want to chose how many players to be in game (for example i press the button with 20 Players ) i want to be redirected to a screen with a question and the answer options ( questions are images displayed in a screen) but i get this error

~ raise ScreenManagerException('No Screen with name "%s".' % name)
kivy.uix.screenmanager.ScreenManagerException: No Screen with name "start". ~

I used the app.root.current multiple times and everytime worked until now and I can't figure out what is wrong ..

Thanks !!

```
ALL PY CODE

from kivy.app import App
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import ScreenManager, Screen
from kivy.properties import ObjectProperty
from kivy.uix.popup import Popup
from kivy.uix.label import Label
from database import DataBase
import random


class CreateAccountWindow(Screen):
    namee = ObjectProperty(None)
    email = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)

    def submit(self):
        if self.namee.text != "" and self.email.text != "" and self.email.text.count("@") == 1 and self.email.text.count(".") > 0:
            if self.password != "":
                db.add_user(self.email.text, self.password.text, self.namee.text)

                self.reset()

                sm.current = "login"
            else:
                invalidForm()
        else:
            invalidForm()

    def login(self):
        self.reset()
        sm.current = "login"

    def reset(self):
        self.email.text = ""
        self.password.text = ""
        self.namee.text = ""


class LoginWindow(Screen):
    email = ObjectProperty(None)
    password = ObjectProperty(None)

    def loginBtn(self):
        if db.validate(self.email.text, self.password.text):
            MainWindow.current = self.email.text
            self.reset()
            sm.current = "main"
        else:
            invalidLogin()

    def createBtn(self):
        self.reset()
        sm.current = "create"

    def reset(self):
        self.email.text = ""
        self.password.text = ""


class MainWindow(Screen):
    n = ObjectProperty(None)
    created = ObjectProperty(None)
    email = ObjectProperty(None)
    current = ""

    def logOut(self):
        sm.current = "login"


class Q1(Screen):
    pass


class Q2(Screen):
    pass


class Q3(Screen):
    pass


class Q4(Screen):
    pass


class WrongAnswer(Screen):
    pass


class TestApp:

    def wrong_answer(self):
        screen = ['WrongAnswer']
        return random.choice(screen)

    def random_screen(self):
        screens = ['Q1', 'Q2', 'Q3', 'Q4']
        return random.choice(screens)

    def build(self):

        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Q1(name='Q1'))
        sm.add_widget(Q2(name='Q2'))
        sm.add_widget(Q3(name='Q3'))
        sm.add_widget(Q4(name='Q4'))
        sm.add_widget(WrongAnswer(name='WrongAnswer'))

        return sm



class WindowManager(ScreenManager):
    pass


def invalidLogin():
    pop = Popup(title='Invalid Login',
                  content=Label(text='Invalid username or password.'),
                  size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))
    pop.open()


def invalidForm():
    pop = Popup(title='Invalid Form',
                  content=Label(text='Please fill in all inputs with valid information.'),
                  size_hint=(None, None), size=(400, 400))

    pop.open()


kv = Builder.load_file("my.kv")

sm = WindowManager()
db = DataBase("users.txt")

screens = [LoginWindow(name="login"), CreateAccountWindow(name="create"),MainWindow(name="main")]
for screen in screens:
    sm.add_widget(screen)

sm.current = "login"


class MyMainApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return sm


if __name__ == "__main__":
    MyMainApp().run()
```

```
ALL KV CODE


<CreateAccountWindow>:
    name: "create"

    namee: namee
    email: email
    password: passw

    FloatLayout:
        cols:1

        FloatLayout:
            size: root.width, root.height/2

            Label:
                text: "Create an Account"
                size_hint: 0.8, 0.2
                pos_hint: {"x":0.16, "top":1}
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

            Label:
                size_hint: 0.5,0.12
                pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.8}
                text: "Name: "
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

            TextInput:
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.38, "top":0.77}
                size_hint: 0.4, 0.075
                id: namee
                multiline: False
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

            Label:
                size_hint: 0.5,0.12
                pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.8-0.13}
                text: "E-Mail: "
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

            TextInput:
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.38, "top":0.65}
                size_hint: 0.4, 0.075
                id: email
                multiline: False
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

            Label:
                size_hint: 0.5,0.12
                pos_hint: {"x":0, "top":0.8-0.125*2}
                text: "Password: "
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

            TextInput:
                pos_hint: {"x": 0.38, "top":0.53}
                size_hint: 0.4, 0.075
                id: passw
                multiline: False
                password: True
                font_size: (root.width**2 + root.height**2) / 14**4

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.60,"y":0.35}
            size_hint: 0.18, 0.075
            font_size: (root.width**2.11 + root.height**2) / 17**4
            text: "Back to Login"
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                root.login()

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.38,"y":0.35}
            size_hint: 0.18, 0.075
            text: "Register"
            font_size: (root.width**1.95 + root.height**2) / 14**4
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "left"
                root.submit()


<LoginWindow>:
    name: "login"

    email: email
    password: password

    FloatLayout:

        Label:
            text:"E-Mail: "
            font_size: (root.width**1.8 + root.height**2) / 13**4
            pos_hint: {"x":0.1, "top":0.9}
            size_hint: 0.40, 0.15

        TextInput:
            id: email
            font_size: (root.width**1.91 + root.height**2) / 13**4
            multiline: False
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.38 , "top":0.86}
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.075

        Label:
            text:"Password: "
            font_size: (root.width**1.8 + root.height**2) / 13**4
            pos_hint: {"x":0.106, "top":0.81}
            size_hint: 0.35, 0.15

        TextInput:
            id: password
            font_size: (root.width**1.91 + root.height**2) / 13**4
            multiline: False
            password: True
            pos_hint: {"x": 0.38, "top":0.77}
            size_hint: 0.4, 0.075

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.38,"y":0.605}
            size_hint: 0.18, 0.075
            font_size: (root.width**1.8 + root.height**2) / 13**4
            text: "Login"
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "up"
                root.loginBtn()

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.60,"y":0.605}
            size_hint: 0.18, 0.075
            font_size: (root.width**2.09 + root.height**2) / 17**4
            text: "Create Account"
            on_release:
                root.manager.transition.direction = "right"
                root.createBtn()


<MainWindow>:

    FloatLayout:
        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x": 0.6, "top":0.9}
            size_hint:0.4, 0.1
            text: "5 Players"

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x": 0.6, "top":0.7}
            size_hint:0.4, 0.1
            text: "10 Players"

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x": 0.6, "top":0.5}
            size_hint:0.4, 0.1
            text: "15 Players"

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x": 0.6, "top":0.3}
            size_hint:0.4, 0.1
            text: "20 Players"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "start"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "down"

        Button:
            pos_hint:{"x":0.04, "y": 0.05}
            size_hint:0.2,0.1
            text: "Log Out"
            on_release:
                app.root.current = "login"
                root.manager.transition.direction = "down"

<Q1>:
    name: "start"
    Image:
        source: 'Q1.png'

        FloatLayout:
            size: root.width, root.height/2

            Button:
                size_hint: 0.3, 0.25
                pos_hint: {"x":0.09, "top":1.16}
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0.2
                on_release: root.manager.current = app.random_screen()

            Button:
                size_hint: 0.3, 0.25
                pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "top":1.16}
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0.2
                on_release: root.manager.current = app.wrong_answer()

            Button:
                size_hint: 0.3, 0.25
                pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "top":0.7}
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0.2
                on_release: root.manager.current = app.wrong_answer()

            Button:
                size_hint: 0.3, 0.25
                pos_hint: {"x":0.09, "top":0.7}
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0.2
                on_release: root.manager.current = app.wrong_answer()


<Q2>:
    Image:
        source: 'Q2.png'

        FloatLayout:
            size: root.width, root.height/2

            Button:
                size_hint: 0.3, 0.25
                pos_hint: {"x":0.09, "top":1.16}
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0.2
                on_release: root.manager.current = app.wrong_answer()

            Button:
                size_hint: 0.3, 0.25
                pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "top":1.16}
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0.2
                on_release: root.manager.current = app.random_screen()

            Button:
                size_hint: 0.3, 0.25
                pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "top":0.7}
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0.2
                on_release: root.manager.current = app.wrong_answer()

            Button:
                size_hint: 0.3, 0.25
                pos_hint: {"x":0.09, "top":0.7}
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0.2
                on_release: root.manager.current = app.wrong_answer()

<Q3>:
    Image:
        source: 'Q3.png'

        FloatLayout:
            size: root.width, root.height/2

            Button:
                size_hint: 0.3, 0.25
                pos_hint: {"x":0.09, "top":1.16}
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0.2
                on_release: root.manager.current = app.wrong_answer()

            Button:
                size_hint: 0.3, 0.25
                pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "top":1.16}
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0.2
                on_release: root.manager.current = app.wrong_answer()

            Button:
                size_hint: 0.3, 0.25
                pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "top":0.7}
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0.2
                on_release: root.manager.current = app.wrong_answer()

            Button:
                size_hint: 0.3, 0.25
                pos_hint: {"x":0.09, "top":0.7}
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0.2
                on_release: root.manager.current = app.random_screen()

<Q4>:
    Image:
        source: 'Q4.png'

        FloatLayout:
            size: root.width, root.height/2

            Button:
                size_hint: 0.3, 0.25
                pos_hint: {"x":0.09, "top":1.16}
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0.2
                on_release: root.manager.current = app.random_screen()

            Button:
                size_hint: 0.3, 0.25
                pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "top":1.16}
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0.2
                on_release: root.manager.current = app.wrong_answer()

            Button:
                size_hint: 0.3, 0.25
                pos_hint: {"x":0.5, "top":0.7}
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0.2
                on_release: root.manager.current = app.wrong_answer()

            Button:
                size_hint: 0.3, 0.25
                pos_hint: {"x":0.09, "top":0.7}
                background_color: 1, 1, 1, 0.2
                on_release: root.manager.current = app.wrong_answer()

<WrongAnswer>:
    Image:
        source: 'L1.png'
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not creating a `start` `Screen`:

```
screens = [LoginWindow(name="login"), CreateAccountWindow(name="create"),MainWindow(name="main")]
```

I see `login`, `create`, and `main`.